# Mac Pro macOS Catalina 10.15.3 Crash&Restart when Xcode 11.4.1 Archive

Tags: crash, kernel-panic

This is the system log

````
 IA32_MC21_STATUS(0x455): 0xbe200000000b110a
 IA32_MC21_ADDR(0x456):   0x000000081dc7ae40
 IA32_MC21_MISC(0x457):   0x88fe28108c9c8086
Processor 12: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC21_STATUS(0x455): 0xbe200000000b110a
 IA32_MC21_ADDR(0x456):   0x000000081dc7ae40
 IA32_MC21_MISC(0x457):   0x88fe28108c9c8086
Processor 13: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC21_STATUS(0x455): 0xbe200000000b110a
 IA32_MC21_ADDR(0x456):   0x000000081dc7ae40
 IA32_MC21_MISC(0x457):   0x88fe28108c9c8086
Processor 14: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC21_STATUS(0x455): 0xbe200000000b110a
 IA32_MC21_ADDR(0x456):   0x000000081dc7ae40
 IA32_MC21_MISC(0x457):   0x88fe28108c9c8086
Processor 15: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC21_STATUS(0x455): 0xbe200000000b110a
 IA32_MC21_ADDR(0x456):   0x000000081dc7ae40
 IA32_MC21_MISC(0x457):   0x88fe28108c9c8086
mp_kdp_enter() timed-out on cpu 9, NMI-ing
mp_kdp_enter() NMI pending on cpus: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10 11 12 13 14 15
mp_kdp_enter() timed-out during locked wait after NMI;expected 16 acks but received 1 after 10962676 loops in 1500000000 ticks
panic(cpu 9 caller 0xffffff8003265b2c): "Machine Check at 0xffffff7f86ac9acb, registers:\n" "CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x00007fef766e0000, CR3: 0x000000001821e000, CR4: 0x00000000001626e0\n" "RAX: 0x0000000000000020, RBX: 0xffffff804ea67380, RCX: 0x0000000000000001, RDX: 0x0000000000000000\n" "RSP: 0xffffff838a8f3d50, RBP: 0xffffff838a8f3d80, RSI: 0x0000000000000006, RDI: 0xffffff804ed56d40\n" "R8:  0xffffff804ed71700, R9:  0xffffff804ea67380, R10: 0x0000000000000005, R11: 0x000000001821e000\n" "R12: 0x0000000000000006, R13: 0xffffff804e6d7a00, R14: 0xffffff7f86adf630, R15: 0x00000000000007b0\n" "RFL: 0x0000000000000046, RIP: 0xffffff7f86ac9acb, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000\n" "Error code: 0x0000000000000000\n"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-6153.81.5/osfmk/i386/trap_native.c:168
Backtrace (CPU 9), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8002f55b10 : 0xffffff800313bb2b 
0xffffff8002f55b60 : 0xffffff80032734d5 
0xffffff8002f55ba0 : 0xffffff8003264f4e 
0xffffff8002f55bf0 : 0xffffff80030e2a40 
0xffffff8002f55c10 : 0xffffff800313b217 
0xffffff8002f55d10 : 0xffffff800313b5fb 
0xffffff8002f55d60 : 0xffffff80038d2aa9 
0xffffff8002f55dd0 : 0xffffff8003265b2c 
0xffffff8002f55ec0 : 0xffffff80038d2c28 
0xffffff8002f55ed0 : 0xffffff80030e329f 
0xffffff838a8f3d80 : 0xffffff7f86abb7f6 
0xffffff838a8f3e60 : 0xffffff7f86abaa36 
0xffffff838a8f3f20 : 0xffffff8003266f6a 
0xffffff838a8f3f40 : 0xffffff8003160a37 
0xffffff838a8f3f80 : 0xffffff8003160bf8 
0xffffff838a8f3fa0 : 0xffffff80030e213e 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement(222.0)[F76E3420-6A3B-3C54-AECF-3CE52F3F1EEC]@0xffffff7f86ab8000->0xffffff7f86ae1fff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
19D76

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.3.0: Thu Jan  9 20:58:23 PST 2020; root:xnu-6153.81.5~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: A8DDE75C-CD97-3C37-B35D-1070CC50D2CE
Kernel slide:     0x0000000002e00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8003000000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8002f00000
System model name: MacPro6,1 (Mac-F60DEB81FF30ACF6)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 45499247424711
last loaded kext at 39590883342888: >usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0 (addr 0xffffff7f87897000, size 20480)
last unloaded kext at 215693274187: >usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0 (addr 0xffffff7f84777000, size 24576)
loaded kexts:
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    7.5.1
>!AFIVRDriver   4.1.0
@nke.rvi    2.0.0
@filesystems.smbfs  3.4.1
@fileutil   20.036.15
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>AGPM   111.4.2
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>!AMCCSControl  1.13
@kext.AMDFramebuffer    3.0.5
>!AHDA  283.15
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000    3.0.5
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   3.0.5
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 4.7.2
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   4.7.2
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.3f5
>pmtelemetry    1
>eficheck   1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!AMGPUPowerControl 4.7.2
@kext.AMD7000!C 3.0.5
>!ALPC  3.1
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.3
>!A!IMCEReporter    115
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.0.9
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.81.1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
|!ABCM5701Ethernet  10.3.5
>!AAHCIPort 341.0.2
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!ARTC  2.0
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
>!A!ICPUPowerManagementClient   222.0.0
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
>!A!ICPUPowerManagement 222.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
>!AThunderboltEDMSink   4.2.2
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  6.2.5
>!AXsanScheme   3
@kext.triggers  1.0
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
@kext.AMDRadeonX4030HWLibs  1.0
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.3.1
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000HWServices  3.0.5
|IOAVB!F    800.17
>!ASSE  1.0
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  569.4
>!AGraphicsControl  4.7.2
@kext.AMDSupport    3.0.5
@!AGPUWrangler  4.7.2
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    4.7.2
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOGraphics!F   569.4
|IOHDA!F    283.15
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    810.1
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   7.0.3f5
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 7.0.3f5
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.3f5
|IO!B!F 7.0.3f5
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.3f5
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHub  1.2
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOSurface  269.6
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.5
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.5
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.0
|IOAHCIBlock!S  316.80.1
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
|IOAHCI!F   290.0.1
>usb.!UEHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UEHCI 1.2
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.80.2
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.0.2
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.40.7
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.0.2
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergePrope```

**it has crashed lot of times, who knows what can I do? **
````